# Does Couchbase have a query language?

Tags: couchbase

Does Couchbase have a query language, its counterpart to SQL, and does it have a concept of "Join"? I am a long-time Codd and Date guy, who recognizes the limitations of that paradigm for certain kinds of data management problems.   If it does have one, what's it called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couchbase has a query language called N1QL. It is SQL like and does have JOINs. It is not production ready yet. Your best source of information is at http://query.couchbase.com.

UPDATE: Couchbase's query language came out in Couchbase 4.0 as of October 6th 2015. Go grab the latest version at [the download page](http://www.couchbase.com/nosql-databases/downloads).

Comment: any idea when it will be production ready? can't seem to find it anywhere in their docs

Comment: @ChickenWing24 It is part of Couchbase 4.0 that just came out in early October. Here is the link to the documentation on N1QL http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/n1ql/n1ql-intro/data-access-using-n1ql.html Also give a read to http://blog.couchbase.com/user-profile-store-advanced-data-modeling

Comment: Thanks a lot Kirk !!  :D